# How can I check that an expression is constant in C?

Tags: c, compile-time, constant-expression

Say I have a scenario where I need to ensure that a value used in my code is a compile-time constant (e.g. perhaps a draconian interpretation of [P10 rule 2](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/10rules.pdf) "fixed loop bounds"). How can I enforce this at the language-level in C?

C supports the notion of *integer constant expression* at the language-level. It must be possible to work out a way to take advantage of this so that only values complying with this specification can be used in expressions, right? e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < assert_constant(10); ++i) {...
```

Some partial solutions that aren't really general enough to be useful in multiple situations:

- **Bitfields:** a classic strategy for implementing `static_assert` in C prior to C11 was to [use a bitfield whose value would be illegal when a condition failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4815532/1366431):

  ```
  struct { int _:(expression); }
  ```

  While this could be easily wrapped for use as part of an expression, it isn't general at all - the maximum value of `expression` "[may] not exceed the width of an object of the type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted" (C11 6.7.2.1), which places a very low portable limit on the magnitude of `expression` (generally likely to be 64). It also may not be negative.
- **Enumerations:** an `enum` demands that any initializing expressions be integer constant expressions. However, an `enum` declaration cannot be embedded into an expression (unlike a `struct` definition), requiring its own statement. Since the identifiers in the enumerator list are added to the surrounding scope, we also need a new name each time. `__COUNTER__` isn't standardized, so there's no way to achieve this from within a macro.
- **Case:** again, the argument expression to a `case` line must be an integer constant. But this requires a surrounding `switch` statement. This isn't a whole lot better than `enum`, and it's the kind of thing you don't want to hide inside a macro (since it will generate real statements, even if they're easy for the optimizer to remove).
- **Array declaration:** since C99, the array size doesn't even have to be a constant, meaning it won't generate the desired error anyway. It also again is a statement that requires introducing a name into the surrounding scope, suffering from the same problems as `enum`.

Surely there's some way to hide the constant check in a macro that's repeatable, passes the value through (so it can be used as an expression), and doesn't require a statement line or introduce extra identifiers?

Comment: Also see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274532/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-an-integral-constant-expression-in-a-c-preprocess?rq=1) ?

Comment: @quantdev *sigh* really thought I'd searched exhaustively for this topic...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out there is a way!

Although locally-allocated arrays are allowed to have variable length in C, the standard explicitly requires that such arrays *not* have an explicit initializer. We can forcibly disable the VLA language feature by giving an array an initializer-list, which will force the array size to be an integer constant expression (compile-time constant):

```
int arr[(expression)] = { 0 };
```

The content of the initializer doesn't matter; `{ 0 }` will always work.

This is still slightly inferior to the `enum` solution because it requires a statement and introduces a name. But, unlike enumerations, arrays can be made anonymous (as compound literals):

```
(int[expression]){ 0 }
```

Since a compound literal has an initializer as part of the syntax, there's no way for it to ever be a VLA, so this is still guaranteed to require `expression` to be a compile-time constant.

Finally, because anonymous arrays are expressions, we can pass them to `sizeof` which gives us a way to passthrough the original value of `expression`:

```
sizeof((char[expression]){ 0 })
```

This has the added bonus of guaranteeing that the array never gets allocated at runtime.

Finally, with a bit more wrapping up, we can even handle zero or negative values:

```
sizeof((char[(expression)*0+1]){ 0 }) * 0 + (expression)
```

This disregards the actual *value* of `expression` when setting the array size (which will always be 1), but still considers its constant status; it then also disregards the size of the array and returns only the original expression, so the restrictions on array size - must be greater than zero - don't need to apply to the returned value. `expression` is duplicated, but that's what macros are for (and if this compiles, it won't be recomputed because a. it's a constant, and b. the first usage is within a `sizeof`). Thus:

```
#define assert_constant(X) (sizeof((char[(X)*0+1]){ 0 }) * 0 + (X))
```

---

For bonus points, we can use a very similar technique to implement a `static_switch` *expression*, by combining array sizes with C11's `_Generic` (this probably doesn't have many practical uses, but might replace some cases of nested ternaries, which aren't popular):

```
#define static_switch(VAL, ...) _Generic(&(char[(VAL) + 1]){0}, __VA_ARGS__)
#define static_case(N) char(*)[(N) + 1]

char * x = static_switch(3,
             static_case(0): "zero",
             static_case(1): "one",
             static_case(2): "two",
             default: "lots");
printf("result: '%s'\n", x); //result: 'lots'
```

(We take the address of the array to produce an explicit pointer-to-array type, rather than let the implementation decide whether `_Generic` promotes arrays to pointers or not; as of April 2016 this ambiguity was fixed in the language by [DR 481](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_481) and its ensuing TC.)

This is slightly more restrictive than `assert_constant` because it won't admit negative values. By putting a `+1` in both the controlling expression *and* all of the case values, though, we can at least let it accept zero.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on my compiler (xcc, which is "gcc" like but for a specific vendor's embedded MCU). If I use `(X)*0` or `(X)-(X)` the compiler seems to be clever and not evaluate it. Instead I used: `#define ASSERT_CONSTANT(X) (sizeof((char[((int)(X)&1)+1]){ 0 })*0 + (X))` which will work for floats and ints.

Comment: @eresonance the `&` may cause trouble, may it not? Does this also work for you: `(sizeof((char[((0+(x)) && 1) + 1]){0}) * 0 + (x))` (had to add 0 because otherwise some compilers warn about integer ops in bool context for x=`3*4`)

Comment: @eresonance or, even better (works with C89 as well) `(sizeof(struct { int :(((0+(x)) && 1) + 1); }) * 0 + (x))`, prefixed with `__pragma(warning(suppress: 4116))` ifdef _MSC_VER

Comment: I think the `&1` is OK, because all you're trying to do is, given a proper constant input for X, make sure the array size is > 0. Whether it's 1 or 2 doesn't really matter. I think... `&&1` would also work fine? But I'm missing what `(0+(x))` is for in your example.