# NOT accepting variables as an argument in a macro

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, firmware, precompile

I want to reduce the chance of mistakes by other developers and I am looking for a solution for limiting the input of macro definition to NOT accept variables as an input.

```
#define TIMEFRAME_MILISEC(X)        ((X))
#define TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(X)        ((X) * TIMEFRAME_MILISEC(1000))
#define TIMEFRAME_MINUTES(X)        ((X) * TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(60))
#define TIMEFRAME_HOURS(X)          ((X) * TIMEFRAME_MINUTES(60))
```

The usual mistake is that the definition is used for the initialization of variables value and after that calling the definition with the variable again.
I just want to be used with "hardcoded" values.

```
TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(5)
```

Comment: _I want to reduce the chance of mistakes by other developers_ Then better don't use macros at all... ;-) Macros are evil in C++. They are namespace agnostic which is always good for bad surprises.

Comment: To ban variables and allow constant literals only seems to be a bad idea as well. Please, keep in mind that [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) are considered bad style.

Comment: `I am looking for a solution for limiting the input of macro definition to NOT accept variables as an input` Does [How to check if a parameter is an integral constant expression in a C preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274532/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-an-integral-constant-expression-in-a-c-preprocess) answer your quesiton?

Comment: Aside do parenthesise the `x` in every definition, not just the first, or the mistake will be yours.

Comment: If you want to protect your developers, do not use macros, but use template functions or constexpr functions those will be typesafe (and the compiler will be your friend). For anything time you should consider using std::chrono (fully tested code available from the standard library, no need to invent your own stuff).

Comment: How about user-defined literals? `1_seconds` and such. But those are a C++ featute. What's you language, C or C++?

Comment: It is a mixture of C and C++ (80% C and 20% C++), the system is resource tight and we do NOT have a lot of freedom for solutions.
The problem is that we have a lot of time frames and some of them are still NOT defined (we are still figuring them out).

Comment: User-defined literals are a zero-cost abstraction most of the time. They should work for you. Also please begin your comments with `@username`, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: *"a mixture of C and C++"* So is a c++-only solution ok or not?

Comment: Most of the (exciting) macro tricks I've seen here so far rely on specific C features which are not allowed in C++. (At best, a tolerant compiler like g++ might accept them if not forced to be standard conform.) If your project contains 20 % C++ code, you can for sure not use a C compiler (at least, not for those 20 % of code). Thus, the C macro tricks are probably useless for you. Maybe, it would've been better to drop the [tag:c] tag before you got this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72909977/7478597)...

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the solution it is going in that direction.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the best solution will be with C or macros because the expressions are used everywhere in the code and in other projects that are written only in C.

Comment: Ultimately, it's customary to only tag one language at a time. If you want a C solution, tag C. If you want a C++ solution, tag C++. If you want both, it's better to ask two questions.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat the project that we are working on is built with GCC. The files are built according to the type and because of it, I am looking for some general solution that could work with C++ and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dirty trick macro such as this:

```
#define ASSERT_INTCONST(X)  ( (int[X]){0} )
```

- In case `X` is an integer constant expression, this will create a temporary compound literal, which we will discard/optimize out.
- In case `X` is a variable expression, there will be a compiler error since compound literals aren't allowed to be of variable length.

Example:

```
#define ASSERT_INTCONST(X) ( (int[X]){0} )
#define TIMEFRAME_MILISEC(X)  ( ASSERT_INTCONST(X), (X) )
#define TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(X)  ( ASSERT_INTCONST(X), (X) * TIMEFRAME_MILISEC(1000))
#define TIMEFRAME_MINUTES(X)  ( ASSERT_INTCONST(X), (X) * TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(60))
#define TIMEFRAME_HOURS(X)    ( ASSERT_INTCONST(X), (X) * TIMEFRAME_MINUTES(60))

int main (void)
{
  int x = TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(3); // ok
  int y=3;
  int z = TIMEFRAME_SECONDS(y); // error: compound literal has variable size
}
```

---

For further type safety such as only allowing certain integer types:

```
#define ASSERT_INTCONST(X) ( (int[X]){ _Generic((X),int:0) } )
```

Now only integer constant expressions of type `int` will get let through. Not `long`, `unsigned int`, `size_t` etc.

Also if the value zero should be allowed, the macro might have to be `(int[(X)+1])` or compiling under strict standard settings may raise complaints about zero-sized arrays.